# Is there a word for a word (ex of ‘word’:near rhyme) that has a rhyme with the middle of a word?

Tags: rhymes

For example, I reaLIzed that you are a LIE

The caps are the rhyming part

Comment: This doesn't really rhyme when you say 'realised' normally. The /lʌɪ/ is unstressed.

Comment: Does *rap lyric* suit your purpose?

Comment: Yes these are rap lyrics I wrote

Answer (score 1):

The only word that comes to mind is *assonance*:

> the repetition of the sound of a vowel (e.g., resonate, implicate, detonate).

Comment: Please add a reference for your quote.